# element with slide toggle inside element with slide toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'd like to stop the slidetoggle from executing if the element clicked is a child element with a slidetoggle.

```
<ul>
  <li class="parentToggle">
    I am the parent

    <ul class="hiddenClass">
      <li class="childToggle">
        I am child. I will be shown when parent is clicked.

        <ul class="hiddenClass2">
          <li>
            I am grandchild. I will be shown when child is clicked.
          </li>
        </ul>

      </li>

      <li class="childToggle">
        I am 2nd child. I will be shown when parent is clicked.

        <ul class="hiddenClass2">
          <li>
            I am grandchild. I will be shown when child is clicked.
          </li>
        </ul>

      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
```

I have the following script.

```
$('.parentToggle').click(function() {
  $(this).find('hiddenClass').slideToggle();
});

$('.childToggle').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.hiddenClass2').slideToggle();
});
```

Based from the behavior, the parentToggle executes when the childToggle is clicked since the child is also part of the parent.

Edit: Updated the code, added another child.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$('.parentToggle').click(function(e) {
if ($(e.target).is('.childToggle')) {//test if the clicked element is the child ,if it is toggle its child ,if it's not toggle the parent slide
   $(e.target).find('.hiddenClass2').slideToggle();
  } else {
  $(this).find('.hiddenClass').slideToggle();
  }
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qqezkLne/1/)

Comment: I updated the code adn added another child. It turns out this solution is only applicable if the parent has only 1 child. If it does have another child, all childs will be affected so instead of showing the grandchild of the specific child clicked, all grandchild from every child will be shown.